# [].include?(:test) return nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, null

Having the strange problem that `[].include?(:test)` returns `nil` instead of expected `false`. The whole thing only happens when running the app (i see it in rubymine debug mode), not in irb or rails console.

I tested the following:

```
[].include?(:test)  # nil

[].include?(:test).nil? # nil

[].class # Array
```

Seems as if include? is overwritten somewhere, but I have not been able to find out where. `grep -R Array * and grep -R include? *` show nothing strange. Any idea how I could find out more?

Comment: Sounds like someone modified Object, or Enumerable. Did you search for those?

Comment: The sample  code that you have posted is behaving as expected. Can you post the actual code that has the issue.

Comment: Nothing suspicious in Object or Enumerable

btw. 

[].include?(:test) # nil

[].include?(:test).class # FalseClass

[].include?(:test).to_s # "False"

Strange.

Comment: @KandadaBoggu - where did you try? In irb/rubyconsole it works fine.
I tested it in an new rails app without any plugins. One controller with one action. Set a breakpoint there and start debug. Code is [].include(:test) (I inspect the code in the rubymine debugger)

Comment: Hmm. It seems to be a problem of the debugger.  It shows nil for [].include?(:test) but true for [].include?(:test)==false . So maybe a problem of rubymine, that just confuses me...

Comment: I have seen this behavior in the debugger before. It should work when you are running your app outside the debugger. Add some print statements in your code and run the app outside the debugger, i.e. `puts ">>>> #{[].include?(:test)}"`

Comment: I have also noticed similar error in Rubymine. It occurs when you trying to inspect something heavy, and it is timeout. Then all inspects in the same debug session return values that are coming with 'delay' - i.e. if you check some array - it will return its inspect if you try several times the same inspect command.

Comment: have you tried to look
[].method(:include?).source_location  ?